# Problem with getting data from mysql in c#

Tags: c#, mysql

My code:

```
DateTime tupdated1;  
tupdated1 = reader.GetDateTime("tupdated");
```

I got some error about:

> MySql.Data.Types.MySqlConversionException: 'Unable to convert MySQL
>   date/time value to System.DateTime'

How can i get timestamp (last updated) from mysql in C#?

Please release me!

Comment: What is the type of the MySQL `tupdated` column?

Comment: Hey, please attach a minimal code on your question, and check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54792728/unable-to-convert-mysql-date-time-value-to-system-datetime-when-not-using-a-da    it's very similar

Comment: this is TIMESTAMP type

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934844/unable-to-convert-mysql-date-time-value-to-system-datetime)

Comment: Does the field contain any invalid values like `0000-00-00`? There's no 0 date. That's a quasi-*un*supported MySQL weirdness - [quasi-unsupported by MySQL itself](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date) that is.

Comment: Another possibility is an illegal date like `2010-04-31` if [ALLOW_INVALID_DATES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_allow_invalid_dates) is set. Depending on *other* settings, this can be allowed or converted to `0000-00-00`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help to me it works!

Comment: @MarcoSalerno the accepted answer isn't a good one - dates have no format. The upvoted answer is a lot better though and could actually help

Answer (score 0):

First Check your DB datasheet data type.

My guess is your wrong use data type.

DateTime is right data type in mysql. not date/Time.

Comment: Unfortunately, MySQL under certain quasi-unsupported conditions allows the invalid value `0000-00-00`

Answer (score 0):

In my data table there is a 0000-00-00 like this date inserted then I changed this date to correctly one like this 2020-01-28